# How do I count how oftens the grades occur in a txt file?

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class GradeDistribution{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
  int count = 0;
  int count2 = 0;
  int count3 = 0;
  int count4 = 0;
  int count5 = 0;


  Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
 while(input.hasNext()){
    try{
       int num = input.nextInt();
       if(num > 90 && num < 100){
       count++;}
       if(num > 80 && num < 89){
       count2++;}
       if(num > 70 && num < 79){
          count3++;}

       if(num > 60 && num < 69){
          count4++;}

       if(num > 60){
          count5++;}




         }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not a valid number");
            input.hasNext();
         }

         }


System.out.println("[90 - 100] " + count);
System.out.println("[80 - 89] " + count2);
System.out.println("[70 - 79] " + count3);
System.out.println("[60 - 69] " + count4);
System.out.println("[below 60] " + count5);


 }

}
```

My output only gives me "Not a valid number" for every single line and I don't even know where to start when trying to fix this. I made the variable for when the code is checking the integers to determine which count to increase and made the if statements to determine where they go.

Comment: Change `while(input.hasNext()){` to `while(input.hasNextInt()){`

Comment: post your input txt file content and we can go from there.

Also I believe you should use ">=" and "else if".

Comment: 67 98
123
GH
 -90
89
100
88
79
94
92
67
80
is the data in the datafile and how should I do the else if statements?

Comment: In your catch block, put this line. e.printStackTrace(). Then try to understand why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

In your while condition you have used hasNext() instead of hasNextInt(). hasNext() 'Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input' and nextInt() 'Scans the next token of the input as an int'.

Lets say sample input is "67 98 123 GH -90 89 100 88 79 94 92 67 80"
If you use debugger you will see that integers before GH is getting processed. When GH is encountered it is printed "Not a valid number" and the cursor remains there. hasNext() is returning true because GH is a valid token but nextInt() is causing exception.

So use hasNextInt(). Now this will not give the desired output because hasNextInt() 'Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value'. When GH is encountered the hasNextInt() will return false and the program will stop.

To make the code work use skip("[^0-9]*") to skip anything which is not an integer. Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;


    Scanner input=new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    while(input.hasNextInt()){
        try{
            int num = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("This is "+num);
            if(num > 90 && num < 100){
                count++;}
            if(num > 80 && num < 89){
                count2++;}
            if(num > 70 && num < 79){
                count3++;}

            if(num > 60 && num < 69){
                count4++;}

            if(num < 60){
                count5++;}

            input.skip("[^0-9]*");


        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Not a valid number");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("[90 - 100] " + count);
    System.out.println("[80 - 89] " + count2);
    System.out.println("[70 - 79] " + count3);
    System.out.println("[60 - 69] " + count4);
    System.out.println("[below 60] " + count5);
}
```